# shell script is not reading $HOME value properly

Tags: shell

I have tried to fetch the value from another file with below code snippet

```
file=`echo "$(read_properties 'abc.config')"` // reading this input from other file
```

- abc.config =$HOME/one/two
- $HOME = /home/cbc

but when i use line number 1, Actual = $HOME/one/two

Expected : /home/cbc/one/two

where if i only print $HOME it gives me output as /home/cbc

but why it is not printing properly when i use in file variable

Comment: How is `abc.config` translated in `$HOME/one/two`?

Comment: Most likely it is because of the use of single quotes which are surrounding the `abc.config`. You might want to change that to double quotes.

Comment: IF the function `read_properties 'abc.config'` returns `$HOME/one/two` then it sees this as a string and `echo` will not translate it. You could pass it to `envsubst` which will do the translation for you. Example `echo '$HOME'` return `$HOME`, but `echo '$HOME' | envsubst` will return `/home/cbc`

Comment: It worked hurray:)

A big thankful to you @kvantour, u saved my day